# Backbone events not fired by a jquery click event inside the view

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I cant figure out why the jquery click event to an event inside the view will not trigger..

I have a backbone view like this:

```
class TreeList extends Backbone.View
    el: "#tree-list"
    events:
        "click li span":"toggleTree"
        "click li .select":"selectChannel"
    template: _.template """
        <ul id="tree"></ul>
    """
    initialize: =>
        $(@el).undelegate('li span', 'click');
        $(@el).undelegate('li .select', 'click');
        $("body").css "cursor", "progress"
        @render()
    render: =>
        $(@el).html @template
        _.each @collection.models, (model) =>
            item = new TreeListItem model:model
            $("#tree").append item.render()
            if model.attributes.selected
                            console.log($("##{model.attributes.ChannelID} .select"))
                $("##{model.attributes.ChannelID} .select")[0].click() # this event is never fired (selectChannel event)
        return this
    toggleTree: (e) =>
        console.log "toggle tree"
    selectChannel: (e) =>
        console.log "selet channel"
```

As you can see Im calling a click event on the element witch fires a **toggleTree** event when I click on it, but not with the jquery click method.

The console.log of that element:

```
[i.icon-check-empty select, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "#d972c967-6b56-40b5-99c9-a25300c03341 .select", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
```

setting the background of the element to black does work..

```
$("##{model.attributes.ChannelID} .select").css
    background:"#000"
```

Can any one shed some light why this is happening?

Comment: well, for one, that isn't the jQuery click method, that's the native dom element click method. (though it should still in theory trigger it, as long as the element exists)

Comment: The element is there, I can console.log it and see in the dom and the html

Comment: possibly triggering the event before it has been bound to?

Comment: The events are bound, just checked

Comment: What are those `undelegate` calls doing in your `initialize`?

Comment: those are so there is no bubbeling of events. I can take it out, it makes no difference. if i dont do that, you start getting multiplying click events

Comment: Multiplying click events suggests that you have a zombie infestation which suggests that you're not properly cleaning up after yourself. Anyway, the basic structure should work so start adding things to http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/GZMBC/ until it stops working.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it and it also does not work. I guess the events are not bound yey like Kevin B suggested? http://jsfiddle.net/7hMMr/

Comment: When are the events actually bound?

Answer (score 0):

I think the element was not added to the DOM tree. Your code is:

```
$("#tree").append item.render()
```

You should have done the following:

```
$("#tree").append item.render().el
```

And the reason why you get a false presence is that you check it using

```
model.attributes.selected
```

Your views of the model were rendered but never added to DOM Tree. I think the best to check if a component exist in your DOM tree is to right click on your "Tree" and use "Inspect Element" function in Firefox or Chrome.